# My pc starts to turn on then turn off again

Tags: windows

Ok guys so lately my pc is acting wierd. It shuts off completely and when I tried to turn it back on it wont power up. So I turned of and on the powersupply but nothing happens. i unplugged the power cable from the power supply and tried to turn it on again but nothing happens. At this point I am late for school so I decided to fix ot later. When I came back home, I tried to turn on my pc and it works for about an hour then completely shutsoff again. I tried to power it on but it keeps on turning on and off, like it will turb for 5 sec and shuts off then repeat the process. At this point I observed the the fans when the pc is turned on is really weak so is my powersupply the problem? Because some people also says that it could be the motherboard or an overheating cpu so I changed the thermalpaste on my cpu but the result is still the same. So I decided to leave my pc off for 1 day and tried it again the other day. The fans are all fast like normally so I thought its fixed but then it did it again so now I am being skeptical on whether the problem is my motherboard or psu. Because if the cpu is the problem I wouldnt be able to go into my desktop right? I know this is very long but I want to be deatailed as possible so that you guys can help me so tldr is my psu the problem or my motherboard?

Comment: People are more likely to read your question if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Comment: Neither answer seems to address the obvious. The system is overheating. Find and replace the faulty fan - probably CPU fan. It's obvious because the system keeps shutting off if you keep trying to turn it on, but it stays on for a period of time AFTER you let it cool down for a while. Also, +1 on @DavidPostill comment.

Answer (score 0):

I cant seem to add a comment yet as lacking reputation but...

Having has this problem myself several times it is most likely one of the below issues

- Faulty memory module, I would take it all out. Make sure is clean memory module and the DDR socket and insert the module back ensuring it snaps in as designed and the tabs close properly. Place only one stick back at a time, and verify if computer is working now. You could have a single faulty memory stick.
- If you are overclocking, reset the bios and try boot up
- If you are not overclocking, reset the bios anyway as something could be slightly corrupt potentially, of course this will reset all of your bios options. If you are inexperienced, take caution especially around AHCI SATA settings

Comment: The thing is I tried to boot it up without the ram and it would still shutdown I am actually planning on removing my powersupply and test it by itself it. If the problem still occurs my only conclusion is that the powersupply went wrong right?

Answer (score 0):

Overheating is pretty easy to confirm or refute. On Windows there is usually a hardware monitor setting somewhere in control panel. If there is not, a program called 'open hardware monitor' can get you the info. It only takes a few seconds so it sounds like you would have enough time to check.

Answer (score 0):

i will just use this instead of comment because of reputation

OKay here is an idea :

1- don't use your computer for 1-5 hours

2- check the bios and then take a look at the system temp, if the system temp is getting hotter, it might be your problem, because if it's not the CPU, it should be the system.

### PS: if that didnt help, give me more details about your problem

My English Is Not The Best

Comment: i already stopped using my pc for about a week now and as for the cpu, I changed the thermal paste of it last week but as of checking for the temp I havent done that yet. If that really is the problem and not the power supply what can I do to fix it?